# Sprite is not showing in game

Tags: unity

I'm new to unity and started learning for 1 week.

But when I add a Sprite and run the game (or check the camera view) I can't see it.

Check this GIF.
https://i.gyazo.com/a54e69096bbd4ef629dcf82b7f90124d.gif

or MP4
https://i.gyazo.com/a54e69096bbd4ef629dcf82b7f90124d.mp4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the Z position of the `Main Camera` is 0, the same as the sprite's one.

Set the Z position of the Camera to a negative value (like the default at -10), and you'll be able to see the sprite rendered by the camera.